# Join tables vs JSON data in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel, eloquent

I am wondering which is the best approach to handle relationships in my data.

My person table currently stores 'name' and 'url' for multiple instances of the following (column names changed for simplicity):

1. Favourite books
2. Favourite websites
3. Favourite shops
4. Favourite places

So, for each of the above, I have a column in the person table containing a JSON string. For example, for a single person, I might have the following in the 'favourite_shops' column:

```
[{"name":"john lewis", "url":"http://www.johnlewis.com"},{"name":"tesco", "url":"http://www.tesco.co.uk"}]
```

And the following in the 'favourite_websites' column

```
[{"name":"bbc", "url":"http://www.bbc.co.uk"},{"name":"the guardian", "url":"http://www.guardian.co.uk"}]
```

Obviously these JSON strings can contain many more items, and this is repeated for the other two columns - 'favourite_books' and 'favourite_places'.

So, one query to the database can return all the data I need. But I must then loop through the JSON in AngularJS for display on the front end.

My question is this - would it be beneficial (especially due to the front end processing required), to have 4 join tables instead of the columns listed above?

Or perhaps a single jointable (as the 4 share the same properties, name and url) with an additional column indicating which of the 4 the row refers to?

Things to add:

1. I am using Laravel 5.2 and Eloquent
2. It is very unlikely I will ever need to display all 'persons' AND their related data at once, the view will be one person at a time.
3. It is also very unlikely I would ever need to query specific items - ie 'favourite_shops' named 'john_lewis' - the data is supplementary to a person.
4. The relationship between person and the 4 options is one to many - persons will not need to share the data, any matching entries are simply additional rows. The actual columns I am using are highly unlikely to have need to share data between persons.
5. I am building the above as a RESTful api, so all data will be json_encoded.

Comment: I know it does not really answer your question but have you take a look at https://github.com/pwm/laravel-jms-serializer ? I use to use the same for Symfony2 framework (https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer)

Comment: Storing serialized data of any form in a database sets my teeth on edge... even in a relatively portable form like JSON. So, personally, I'd go with as many link tables as needed to keep the database as close to 3NF as practical. That way the data itself is still useful and portable even when you've completely rewritten the application from the ground up.

Comment: I'm with @CD001. Each of those columns should be a table linked to the person. It **will** be beneficial to use joined table queries vs front-end parsing of what has the potential to be a very large json string. You also benefit by not having to create the json in the first place. Updates and deletes on any given "Favourite" will be greatly simplified also.

Comment: thanks both, out of interest would you say the same if I were needing to loop through 'person' entries and their associated joint table data - be one hell of a loop of database queries!

Comment: Laravel can handle that for you and it's called eager loading.  It would be a query for all the people, then a query for each item you are looking to join on.  So if you have books, websites, shops, and places, you are looking at 5 queries and Laravel nests them correctly for you.

Comment: @user3158900 eager loading seems exactly what I need, and serves to back up what the other two comments have suggested, that this is a very efficient way of querying joined data. If you want to stick it in an answer with a bit of explanation for others who reach this page, I'll happily accept